# asio boost socket connection refused

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I'm attempting to connect a client and server through asio boost but my connection keeps getting refused. My expected output is a clean connection with no errors.

client.cpp

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    io_service io_service;
    ip::tcp::socket client_socket(io_service);
    client_socket.connect(
        tcp::endpoint(address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 1234));
}
```

server.cpp

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using ip::tcp;

int main() {
    io_service io_service;

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_server(
        io_service, tcp::endpoint(address ::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 1234));

    ip::tcp::socket server_socket(io_service);

    acceptor_server.accept(server_socket);
}
```

This is my error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of                                                       
      'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  connect: Connection refused
  Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, with all the unhygienic namespace ... abuse and then even naming your variables conflicting names (like `io_context`) it's hard to tell wether the code is correct, or should even compile.

Here's my counter-offer

- File `server.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

   int main() {
       boost::asio::io_service ctx;

       tcp::acceptor s(ctx, tcp::endpoint({}, 1234));
       tcp::socket conn = s.accept();
   }
  ```
- File `client.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

   int main() {
       boost::asio::io_service ctx;
       tcp::socket s(ctx);
       s.connect(tcp::endpoint({}, 1234));
   }
  ```

See them [Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Y6a3Pzrs9).

Unsurprisingly that works (see **that** live on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe79834a29c7a57e) with a combined source).

Now if it doesn't work for you then:

- maybe you are not running the code you think you are (check the build is up to date)
- maybe you are running in virtualized/isolated environments (like a docker container?)
- maybe you're in fact not having/keeping the server running while the client is started
- maybe there's a permission/firewall issue
- maybe there's a broken assumption (like, e.g. if you don't realize the server exits after a single connect or a network config change e.g.)